# Python: Multiple if conditions depending on parameter

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, if-statement, scipy

I have the following problem. I have a paramter frc_size. Depending on the size of fcr_size more distances have to be checked in the if conditions. Is there a way to handle that smart and to shorten all these expressions?. For example for fcr_size = 3 the if conditions would look like:

```
minusscore = 2

for coords in full_box:
    mindist = float("inf")
    for m in range(len(lineSegmentPairs[0])):
        newdist = dist(lineSegmentPairs[0][m], lineSegmentPairs[1][m], coords)
        if newdist<mindist:
            mindist=newdist
    if mindist <= radius :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) - minusscore
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +1) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 3
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +2) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 2
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +3) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 1
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist > (radius +3) :
        continue
```

But if the fcr_size would be 4, than a additional if condition would be necessary like:

```
minusscore = 2

for coords in full_box:
    mindist = float("inf")
    for m in range(len(lineSegmentPairs[0])):
        newdist = dist(lineSegmentPairs[0][m], lineSegmentPairs[1][m], coords)
        if newdist<mindist:
            mindist=newdist
    if mindist <= radius :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) - minusscore
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +1) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 4
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +2) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 3
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +3) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 2
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist <= (radius +4) :
        val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + 1
        sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
    elif mindist > (radius +4) :
        continue
```

Comment: Your actions for `mindist <= (radius +4)` and `mindist <= (radius +3)` are the same, is it a typo ?

Comment: I suggest you use 4 spaces instead of 8 for indentation. It will definitely improve readability see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: yeah, i edited it how it would look like for fcr_size 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps something like this?

```
if mindist <= radius:
  val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) - minusscore
  sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
elif mindist > (radius + fcr_size):
  continue
else:
  for i in range(fcr_size):
    if mindist <= radius + i + 1:
      val1 = int(sparse1.get(coords,"0")[0]) + (fcr_size - i)
      sparse1[coords] = [str(val1)]
      break
```

Comment: I think you want `radius + i + 1` in the `if` statement.

Comment: But how could i include the argument mindist <= radius, which gives no matter how the fcr_size is a minus score in the action. If i try to use elif for the for loop it dont works

Comment: @Varlor `if mindist <= radius : # do stuff else: # do for loop` is probably the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: yeah this will work. But i have another problem. With your approach, it will do all actions for every if conditions. In my code the elif condition will only do one action. If the mindist is for example smaller/qual than radius+1 my action will add a score +4 and all other if conditions are ignored. But in your code of course the mindist smaler/equal than radius+1 will fullfuill every condition.

Comment: @Varlor just throw in a break statement. I'll modify answer to show.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the code in the if statements follow a pattern and could be turned into a for loop. Each `elif` statement could be one iteration of the loop with a variable instead of the hardcoded numbers.  It would reduce the size of your code significantly

Comment: … and make it more flexible.